# Excel 2016 and MySQL: Initialization of the data source failed

Tags: mysql, excel

**Situation:**
Fresh installation of Windows 10 x64
Fresh installation of Excel 2016 (16.0.4266.1001) x86
MySQL 5.2.26 x64 on Server 2008 R2
I made a SQL User with all rights on the particular database

**Goal:**
Fetch and analyze MySQL data with Excel

**First steps:**
When you want to connect to MySQL with the built-in Power Query component in Excel 2016 you first get the alert to install MySQL Connector/Net 6.6.5. So I closed Excel, installed the connector, and opened Excel again to connect to the database.

Connecting goes perfectly so far. I can select a table, play with the data in the query window, and load the data in the worksheet.

**Problem:**
After loading the data in the worksheet, before it's fully loaded, you get the alert:

> **Initialization of the data source failed.**

Only after removing the worksheet the query is working again (but only in the query window).

**Possible answers:**

1. According to Microsoft this failure happens when you load an new workbook (made in Excel 2016) in an older version of Excel. But that's not the case. It's a brand new installation (tested on two computers), brand new query, 100% Excel 2016.
2. Try with a minimal set of data
   *I filtered the query to only contain one row without special characters to exclude possible wrong encoding. But even with one row and one column, the error pops up.*
3. Use MySQL for Excel.
   *Possible, but Microsoft and MySQL are providing the MySQL connector, and I want to solve it this integrated way.*
4. Use the newest Connector/Net 6.6.9.
   *Same problem...*

Comment: Do you by any chance have any old add ins that are hanging about?

Comment: No, only the add-ins that are delivered with Excel 2016. It's a completely fresh installation.

Comment: I read power query is broken except for certain elite versions of Excel. Took me once an hour to find the microsoft link on it

Comment: How do you mean? Power Query is integrated in Excel since the 2016 version. Older versions had a seperate app. For what it's worth, I use Excel Pro Plus 2016.